# How to change opus to pcm with discordjs/opus

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an application where I send audio data via WebSockets and save it on the server side. I'm using `@discordjs/opus` for the encoding and decoding of Opus data. But I'm facing an error related to corrupted compressed data. Below is my code:

**server.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const http = require('http');
    const WebSocket = require('ws');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const {OpusEncoder, OpusDecoder} = require('@discordjs/opus');    
    const app = express();
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
    const saveDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'test', 'sound_test');

    if (!fs.existsSync(saveDirectory)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(saveDirectory, { recursive: true });
    }

    const samplingRate = 16000;
    const channels = 1;


    wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
        console.log('Client connected');
        const headers = req.headers;
       const decoder = new OpusEncoder(samplingRate, channels);

        const pcmFilePath = path.join(saveDirectory, path.parse(headers.filename).name +. ".pcm");
        const pcmWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(pcmFilePath);

        ws.on('message', (opusChunk) => {
            try {
                // const encodedChunk = decoder.encode(opusChunk);
                // console.log(opusChunk)
                // console.log(encodedChunk)

                const decodedChunk = decoder.decode(Buffer.from(opusChunk));
                console.log(opusChunk);
                pcmWriteStream.write(decodedChunk);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error while decoding opusChunk:', error);
            }
        });

        ws.on('close', () => {
            pcmWriteStream.end();
            console.log('Client disconnected');
        });
    });

    server.listen(3001, () => {
        console.log("Server listening on port 3000...");
    });`
```

**client.js**

```
    const websocket = require('ws');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const folderPath = path.join(__dirname, 'sound');
    const audiofiles = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);
    audiofiles.forEach(audioFile => {
    var vrcodec = audioFile.endsWith('.opus') ? "OPUS_16K" : "PCM_16K";
    console.log(audioFile)
    console.log(vrcodec);
    const ws = new websocket('ws://localhost:3001', {
        headers: {
        
            filename: audioFile,
            vrcodec: vrcodec
        }
    });

    ws.onopen = () => {
        console.log('Connected to the server');
        const filePath = path.join(folderPath, audioFile);
        const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
        const chunkSize = audioFile.endsWith('.opus') ? 640 : 1024;

        for (let i = 0; i < fileData.length; i += chunkSize) {
            const end = Math.min(i + chunkSize, fileData.length);
            const chunk = fileData.slice(i, end); 
            ws.send(chunk);
        }
    };

    ws.onclose = () => {
        console.log('Disconnected from the server');
      };
    });
```

**error**

> Error while decoding opusChunk: TypeError: The compressed data passed is corrupted

*console.log(opusChunk)*

`<Buffer ef 68 a8 df 37 5f cb dd bb 53 d9 db 2d 47 26 db d9 38 23 dc 83 25 fd dd 36 08 23 df d6 e0 2f de 40 bb 97 da 18 9e e2 d4 c5 8b 8a ce d0 82 aa c9 17 80 ... 3790 more bytes>` ...

Initially, I implemented it using opuscript, but when I decoded the data (buffer) from the client, I encountered an invalid packet error, and when I used Buffer.from() to resolve this, I didn't see the error, but when I checked the pcm file with audacity, I didn't find the amplitude.

So I changed the method to discordjs/opus, and now it's like this.

I'm a new employee who has joined the company for two weeks.